# Effect of Javascript on hovering over an image

Tags: javascript, php, css, image, hover

I m building a website. In this, When I hover over an image I want that some options appear over it such as no.of likes, comments, photographer, etc to be displayed dynamically from the database. Please help me get an idea about how to do this.

Comment: show us what have you tried

Comment: Inspect a site that does what you want. Or just google for one of the 2538255 posts about this topic [which btw needs just CSS and no js].

Comment: You need hover function, if you use jQuery it would be much easier.

Comment: At the very least we need to see your HTML for this. I'm assuming that there is a wrapper which holds the image and another div holding this meta data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/4yhKP/25/)

Try this

```
$(function () {
    $('.client').on("mouseenter", function () {
        $(this).find(".client_slider").animate({
            "bottom": "-240px"
        }, "slow");
    }).on("mouseleave", function () {
        $(this).find(".client_slider").animate({
            "bottom": "-320px"
        }, "fast");
    });
});
```

Hope this helps, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this with JQuery:

```
$(".my-image-class").hover( function () {
  $('.options-menu').fadeIn('slow');
}
```

Code above assumes that your image has CSS class `my-image-class` and your options div has CSS class `options-menu`.

Comment: thank you firstly. But the problem is i need those options/div to appear over the image-div nt anywhere else on the page

Answer (score 1):

HTML and php

```
<div id='imageinfo'>
    <img src'yourfile' id='myimage'>
    <div id='option'><?php //PHP dynamic code here for option ?></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script>
  $('#option').hide(); //hide the option div by default 
  $("#myimage").hover( 
  function () {                      //Mouse In Function 
      $('#option').fadeIn('slow');
  },function () {                   // Mouse Out Function  
      $('#option').fadeOut('slow');
  });
</script>
```

CSS

```
#imageinfo{
position:relative; 
}
 #option{
position:absolute;
z-index:9999;
bottom:0;
}
```

Now #option id content come over the picture , you can put you option ,likes in option div

You can use class to handle multiple images on same page

Comment: if you still have doubt , let me know .....

Answer (score 1):

Just create a div apply positioning absolute to that div. The position will same as the position of your image. Then  change the z-index the z-index of div must be lower than z-index of image. After that write a script to increase z-index of div higher than z-index of image.

Eg:

```
<style type="text/css">
#div{
position:absolute;
top:10px;
left:10px;
z-index:-1000;
}
#image{
position:absolute;
top:10px;
left:10px;
z-index:100;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#image").hover(function()
{
$("#div").css("z-index","1000");
}
});
</script>

<body>
   <img src="http://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/gethired/img/english-728c.png?v=7641486da3a3" id="image">
     <div id="div">
        <p>
Like:50;
comment:10
         <p>
     </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If this answer useful for you don't forgot to mark as right answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is oft-called a `tooltip`.

A good starting point would be using the jQuery UI tooltip: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

If you include jQuery and jQueryUI in your head you can do the following:

HTML

```
<p title="Simple tooltip content">Hover over me</p
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
   $(document).tooltip();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vkj5y/

If you wish to include HTML in your tooltip, you can still put it in the title and call the tooltip plugin this way:

```
$(document).tooltip({
    content: function () {
        return $(this).prop('title');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wnRN7/3/

A more advanced library is here: http://qtip2.com/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will have to define the treatment you want ( no.of likes, comments, photographer ...)
like this :

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript"> 
function yourFunction(q){ 
//Treatment you want 
} 
</script>
```

After this, all you will have to do is to associate the call of your function with the 'onmouseover' event catcher.
like this :

```
<a href="#" id="home">
    <img id="yourImageId" src="pathOfYourImage"onmouseover="yourFunction(q);" />
</a>
```

Comment: yes. But how will that new div area containing the features appear over the image. like it is here for eg. www.weheartit.com

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://www.stepbystep.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/How-to-Apply-Blush-on-Oval-Face.jpg" class="myimg"/>
    <div class="options">
        <ul>
            <li>Like : 5 </li>
            <li>Comment: 6</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.options{
    display:none;
    margin-top:-100px;
}

.myimg{

}
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $(".myimg").hover(function(){
        $(".options").show(1000);
    }, function(){
        $(".options").hide(1000);
    });
});
```

Check demo : http://jsfiddle.net/alaminopu/eKhsC/